# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{2}\sqrt{x^3+1} dx+\int_{1}^{3}\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}dx$ without computation?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate:
$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{2}\,\sqrt{\, x^{3} + 1\,}\,\,{\rm d}x
+\int_{1}^{3}\,\sqrt[3]{\, x^{2} - 1\,}\,\,{\rm d}x$

This problem came with a hint that said to "Think about how the two functions are related". This is for an Adv Calc course that has required little-to-no actual computation. This leads me to believe there is something I am suppose to be recognizing about these integrals ( perhaps without doing any lengthy work ).

Is there some neat observation about these two that I am missing ?, Or, am I over thinking it and it simply requires a long/boring work through to get the answer ?. Running these through a program yields ~$6$ which doesn't seem all that special if there is an observation to make.

Comment: See also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young%27s_inequality

Comment: The area of these two form a square?

Comment: Not a square, but similar.

Comment: @Vincent I've added an image!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**Hint:**

Let $f(x)=\sqrt{x^3+1} $ then $ f^{-1}(x)=\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}$

**Another Hint:**

$\hskip 1 in$
[image]

Comment: I'm with you on the inverse business, but I think there may still be a detail I'm missing to use that information in an intelligent way.

Comment: @Vincent I'm trying to show the graph but I don't have good graphing software so...

Comment: So, not a square, but a rectangle!

Comment: @Vincent Yup! a marvelous $2\times 3$ rectangle!

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now if only I could see things like that myself.

Comment: I wonder, how it is related to Young's inequality according to which $\int_0^2f(x)dx+\int_0^3f^{-1}(x)dx=2\cdot 3=6$ (see e.g. Lemma 2 in http://www.emis.de/journals/JIPAM/images/289_06_JIPAM/289_06_www.pdf). The problem here is that the second integral is from 1 and not 0. But it still holds. Is the integral $\int_0^1\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}dx=0$?

Comment: @pisoir Let me take a look at but one can obviously see that $$\int_0^1\sqrt[3]{x^2-1}\,\mathrm dx\lt0$$

Comment: @Integrator, I found that the condition for Young's inequality (equality in this case) is that $f(0)=0$, which we don't have. I guess, that is the difference.

Comment: @pisoir Maybe you're right! Cheers!

Comment: @Integrator, good solution.